# To list files based on unique part of the filename in Unix

Tags: unix, uniq

I've a directory with below files in it -

```
111-xxx-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
111-xxx-typec_2015-10-14.csv.gz
222-yyy-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
222-yyy-typec_2015-10-14.csv.gz
333-zzz-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
333-zzz-typec_2015-10-14.csv.gz
444-ppp-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
444-ppp-typec_2015-10-14.csv.gz
444-ppp-typec_2015-10-15.csv.gz
```

I want to see the oldest file of each type (xxx, yyy, etc) only, i.e. the output should be,

```
111-xxx-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
222-yyy-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
333-zzz-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
444-ppp-typec_2015-10-13.csv.gz
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: These aren't the latest... but the oldest. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @jens sorry, I've updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is do an 'ls', pipe it through an 'AWK' script where you match the 'type', and check it against a dictionary. If it is in the list, ignore, otherwise print and add to list.

Something like this nawk script:

```
{
   match($0, /(.*)-typec/, m);
   if (matches[m[1]] == "")
   {
      print ;
      matches[m[1]] = m[1];
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot.